# How to prevent cypress from printing secrets in the request body?

Tags: security, cypress

So we're doing the following in our cypress tests:

```
  login(user: SimpleUser) {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${this.apiUrl}/login`,
      body: {
        username: user.email,
        password: "mypassword",
      }
    })
      .should(assertStatusOk)
      .then((resp) => {
        ...
```

which is pretty similar to what they suggest on their page.

However, when the login fails, it then logs to the console:

```
The request we sent was:

Method: POST
URL: myurl
Headers: {
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "user-agent": "myuseragent",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "content-length": mycontentlength
}
Body: {"username":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}
```

where the real password is logged. Can this be prevented? I've read in other threads to add the `{log: false}` option when doing a `cy.type`, but for `cy.request` this doesn't seem to have an impact. Any ideas how I can prevent cypress from printing the full body?

Answer (score 4):

In the case of status code errors, you can add `failOnStatusCode: false` to the request options.

```js
cy.request({
  method: "POST",
  url: `http://example.com/login`,
  failOnStatusCode: false,
  log: false,
  body: {
    username: user.email,
    password: "mypassword",
  }
})
.should('have.property', 'status', '200')
```

Then all you see is **expected { Object (body, headers, ...) } to have property status of '200', but got 404**.

If you have other error types than bad status code, substituute a plain [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for `cy.request()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it took me a while to find a solution. It doesn't help to pass the `{ log: false }` option to `cy.request`, because that doesn't apply to the output message of a test failure. Instead, you can change the output behavior by using `Cypress.on('fail', fn)` in your support file. If you want to keep the rest of the log but remove the password, you can do something like this:

```
Cypress.on('fail', e => {
    const passwordRegex = myRegexThatFindsPasswordText;
    const passwordMatch = e.message.match(passwordRegex);

    if (passwordMatch !== null) {
        e.message = e.message.replace(passwordRegex, '[FILTERED]');
    }

    // Rethrow the error in order to retain the test's failed status
    throw e;
});
```